# PDFBox Nested Colored Tables with Word Wrap

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am trying to create a table which has multiple nested and formatted tables or rows in it. Currently I have created this [image: current progress], whereas i am trying to create something more similar to this [image: where this would represent ONE entry in the table]. My data comes from a xml file which i have full access to. I was trying to do this in **PDFBox 2.0**, but my question would be, is there a better api to use or some other java pdf library. Any tips would be greatly appreciated. I can post my code as well if that will help but i am looking more for some guidance.

Comment: there are some libraries on top of PDFBox such as https://github.com/GlenKPeterson/PdfLayoutManager which might be easier to work with given that PDFBox is missing a high level API for text formatting. As you have xml files you might also take a look at Apache FOP which uses XSL:FO and has a very good PDF output support (in addition to some other formats)

Comment: https://github.com/dhorions/boxable